# Where does Eclipse install maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

As far as I know eclipse ships with maven already installed. But in order to set up my M2_HOME in order to work with maven from the command line I need to know where eclipse stores it?

I don't want to download maven separate and have 2 instances of that on my PC. That can only create headaches.

Comment: Having a separate command line version of Maven allows you to use a different version than the one embedded in Eclipse, and you are also certain that you are using the official environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Eclipse there is only installed a maven-embedder which is a part of Maven which means you have to install maven for the command line separately.

Answer (score 1):

Maven plugin, uses java implementation for calling maven.

What you can do is download and unzip/untar maven for mvn command-line scripts and bin, later you can configure eclipse to point to your created maven home.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Embedded Maven is installed into:
\plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_XXX
Where XXX - version and timestamp